# How to grow right div accordingly?

Tags: html

We plan to have two div as below. The left div we plan to keep it fix with any resolution. The right div the map we plan to grow the width according to the resolution how achieve that?

```
<body>
<div id="left" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px; width:220px;">
</div>

<div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:250px; width:780px; height:100%">Map goes here.
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking like this : http://jsfiddle.net/BNvke/2/

**CSS**

```
#left {
width:220px;
float:left;
background:red;
}

#map {
background:yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="left">stackoverflow
</div>

<div id="map" >Map goes here.
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried like this and I notice I must put the left settings in my case for the id="map" else is does not work. My next problem is that in the left div I got another div gpsDataDiv and inside it I put a table and the problem now it that the moment there is a lot of data the table goes down very long. <div id="left" style="width:220px;height:350px;float:left;background:red;">
     <div id="gpsDataDiv" style="height:350px;float:auto;background:white;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="map" style="top:0px;left:220px; width:100%; height:100%">Map goes here.
  </div>

Comment: I have managed to solve it via this   <div id="left" style="width:220px;height:350px;float:left;background:white;">
     <div id="gpsDataDiv" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 400px;background:white;"></div>. The problem now in chrome it works fine. In IE there is a space gap between the left and map and on firefox it does not load at all. What could be the problem?
  </div>
  <div id="map" style="top:0px;left:220px;height:100%">Map goes here.
  </div>